# Wordpress: Get posts by categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a bit of a wordpress newbie and was trying to find good solution what I was trying to do. Essentially I to get a list of categories that have a specific tag 'detination'. Once I do this I want to query for all posts with the above filter as well.

So What I have now is something like this:

```
$destCategories = get_categories( array('tag' => 'destination' , 'exclude' => '1') );
$posts = get_posts($destCategories);
```

However, get_categories returns an Array of category specific information which can't really be used as a filter for get_posts. Does anyone have suggestions on how can solve this? I could essentially manually iterate through the destCategories array and construct a string of all the category names and use that as a filter in get posts, but I wanted to know if there's a more elegant solution that might be available.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is `tag` in here? Category name/slug? Anyway, `get_posts` accepts a `tax_query` parameter to get only posts specified by that sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

There's no tag argument for get_categories() : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Parameters
I guess you could try passing in a taxonomy array, I don't know how it's gonna work out though.
If you want to get posts by tag, you could just use get_posts() : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters

You could try something like this :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tag' => 'destination',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($query->have_posts()):
    while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i ended up with something like this, which seems to work:

```
    $query = get_posts( $myfilter );
    $destCategories = get_categories( array('tag' => 'destination' , 'exclude' => '1') );

?>

<div id="main">
    <div id="content clearfix">
        <p>this is using front-page.php</p>
        <?php //echo var_dump($destCategories) ?>
        <?php 
        if ( have_posts( $myfilter ) ) {
            foreach ( $destCategories as $category ) :
                $posts = get_posts( array('category_name' => $category->slug) );
                    foreach ( $posts as  $post ) :
 ?>
               <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php echo the_title(); ?> </a></h3>

                <?php
                    endforeach;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    //the_content();
            endforeach;
?>
```